# exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid callback:

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have already tried all the answers which are posted but I could not get any helpful answer which will solve my problem.

I have checked the database also to check the status of my cron. But it gives the error.

My folder structure is following:
  app/code/local/Satish/Cron/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Satish_Cron>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Satish_Cron>
      </modules>
      <global>
        <models>
            <satish_cron>
                <class>Satish_Cron_Model</class>
            </satish_cron>
        </models>
      </global>  
         <crontab> 
            <jobs>            
                <satish_cron>
                    <schedule>
                        <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
                    </schedule>
                    <run>
                        <model>cron/cron::oredrStatus</model>
                    </run>
                </satish_cron>            

            </jobs>
        </crontab>
    </config>
```

app/code/local/Satish/Cron/Model/Cron.php

```
    class Satish_Cron_Model_Cron{
        public function oredrStatus(){ 
          /*My code*/
        }

    }
```

If anyone knows this, please help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `<model>cron/cron::oredrStatus</model>` to `<model>satish_cron/cron::oredrStatus</model>`